# Need help deciphering... possibly a Polybius square

Tags: cipher

"Find the coordinates, get out of the square. Then take one step back and see the answer."
44 – 45 – 51 – 15 – 55 – 22 – 35 – 43 – 55 – 35 – 51 – 43 – 32 – 35 – 34 – 23 – 45 – 21 – 44 – 45 – 13 – 55 – 33 – 12 – 12 – 33 – 25 – 24 – 21 – 34

Using the Polybius square, I got this answer: TUVEZGPSZPVSMPOHUFTUCZNBBNKIFO

However, seems like it doesn't make sense at all. I think I still have to "get out of the square then take one step back." Any ideas?

Comment: What is this from?

Answer (score 6):

Taking "one step back" hints at

> A Caesar cipher of left shift 1, i.e., applying a rot25.

Doing so yields:

> STUDYFORYOURLONGTESTBYMAAMJHEN, that is, **Study for your long test by Maam Jhen.**